# Padding not supported: OAEPPadding

Tags: java, encryption, saml, opensaml, nosuchpaddingxception

I'm attempting to create a functionality that reads certificates from the Windows store. My setup involves an SSO-SAML enabled environment with ADFS as the identity provider (IdP). I've enabled encryption for the assertion. However, I'm encountering a problem during the assertion decryption process. To decrypt the assertion, I've extracted the private key from the MMC. But on attempting to decrypt the assertion using this key, I get the

```
javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException: Padding not supported: OAEPPadding exception.
```

I am using `OpenSaml-2` with `xmlsec-2.1.7`.

Could anyone please guide to resolve this issue.

Please find the code below.

```
public static Assertion getDecryptedAssertion(EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion, 
        KeyStoreWrapper ksWrapper) throws Exception {

    ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver keyResolver = new ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver();
    keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
    keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new EncryptedElementTypeEncryptedKeyResolver());
    keyResolver.getResolverChain().add(new SimpleRetrievalMethodEncryptedKeyResolver());
        
    // Create the credentials.
    BasicX509Credential decryptionCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
    decryptionCredential.setPrivateKey(ksWrapper.getPrivateKeyNew());

    StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver resolver = new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(decryptionCredential);

    // Create a decrypter.
    Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(null, resolver, keyResolver);
    decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
    decrypter.setJCAProviderName("SunMSCAPI");

    // Decrypt the assertion.
    Assertion decryptedAssertion = null;
        
    try {
        decryptedAssertion = decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error while decrypting the saml response ASSERTION.", e);
    }
    return decryptedAssertion;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: MMC is not the Windows cert/key store, only a tool that among other things can operate _on_ that store. If you mean you used MMC to 'extract' (export) the privatekey _and_ cert _from_ the store _to_ a file (probably PFX/PKCS12) use that file with the standard provider(s) (which do support OAEP) NOT SunMSCAPI (which doesn't).

Comment: Minor nitpick and slight annoyance: the `Assertion decryptedAssertion = null;` assignment to `null` is not required: one branch assigns a value and the other branch throws an exception, which exits the scope in which the variable is required. This is often the problem of the IDE which starts off with the idiotic `printStackTrace` without actually stopping execution (which is why I let the application throw an `Error` or `RuntimeException` instead.